# What's the best way to seamlessly load a page with javascript elements?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm super new to frontend, so apologies if this is pretty basic.

I'm trying to create a web interface where users can upload and store their own files. I have the basic functionality working, but currently elements like the metadata table that I'm generating from a Firebase database loads quite a bit after the rest of the page *on every page load*.

I've tried using a preloader effect using jQuery, but for whatever reason I couldn't get the Firebase stuff to preload - it always appeared *after* the preloader was done. I've also thought about saving the metadata locally to speed things up, but that sounds like bad practice / a security concern. I guess I'm just asking for some pointers since I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Here's some relevant code:

```
function main() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // user is signed in.
            var uid = user.uid;
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            document.getElementById('user-name').textContent = displayName;

            // populate table from database metadata
            var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('uploaded-files').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    // generate rows
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    main();
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're serious about doing it professionally, you need to concatenate all your js (firebase sdk and your script.js) and css into one minified file. Each file fetch is expensive in terms of HTTP session establishment time. ...so only one external js and css file.

Grunt is what I use to automate this. See [here for an EZ quickstart Grunt guide](https://hightechtele.com/articles/grunt-getting-started). Same for CSS. Only have one. Even minimize the HTML.

Put your `script.min.js`tag just inside the closing body tag and get rid of the .onload function alltogether.

Have a loader display hardcoded in your HTML UI and swap it out w the data after your fetch resolves. That way the user knows your page/app is loading.

As for responsiveness, [Google's tutorial on building Progressive Web apps](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#differentiating_the_first_run) talks about caching data in session/local storage so you can get your UI up right away, even if the data is stale, while your asynch fetching resolves.

```css
.loading-dot {
  animation: blink 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;   
}
.loading-dot:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-right: 2.5em;
}
.loading-dot:nth-of-type(2){
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.loading-dot:nth-of-type(3){
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.loading-dot:nth-of-type(4){
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.loading-dot:nth-of-type(5){
  margin-right: .5em;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0%   {opacity:0; margin-left:3em; }

  95%  {opacity:1; margin-left:0em; margin-right:-.2em; }
  99%  {opacity:0; }
  100% {margin-left: -1em; margin-right:-.4em;}
}
```

```html
<span class="loading-dot">.</span>
<span class="loading-dot">.</span>
<span class="loading-dot">.</span>
<span class="loading-dot">.</span>
<span class="loading-dot">.</span>
```